# PHP Use Keyword Namespace Not Finding Class

Tags: php, class, google-api

Weirdness. Any ideas why it can't find the class?

Directory Tree:

```
test2.php
 - src
   - Google
     - Spreadsheet
        DefaultServiceRequest.php
        ServiceRequestInterface.php
        Google_Client.php
        ...
```

test2.php:

```
namespace src\Google\Spreadsheet;

require_once 'src/Google/Spreadsheet/ServiceRequestInterface.php';
require_once 'src/Google/Spreadsheet/DefaultServiceRequest.php';
require_once 'src/Google/Spreadsheet/Google_Client.php';

use Google\Spreadsheet\ServiceRequestInterface;
use Google\Spreadsheet\DefaultServiceRequest;
use Google\Spreadsheet\ServiceRequestFactory;

function getGoogleTokenFromKeyFile($clientId, $clientEmail, $pathToP12File) {
    require 'src/Google/Spreadsheet/Google_Client.php';
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setClientId($clientId);

    $cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
        $clientEmail,
        array('https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds'),
        file_get_contents($pathToP12File)
    );

    $client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);

    if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
    }

    $service_token = json_decode($client->getAccessToken());
    return $service_token->access_token;
}

$serviceRequest = new DefaultServiceRequest(getGoogleTokenFromKeyFile(..., ..., ...));
ServiceRequestFactory::setInstance($serviceRequest);
```

Not sure if this is Google API related or what. Something weird is the ServiceRequest classes wouldn't work until I required them. When I didn't, it said it couldn't find it... And when I tried adding src/ to the use path, didn't work, and I tried removing the path all together, all did nothing.

Error: Fatal error: Class 'src\Google\Spreadsheet\Google_Client' not found in test2.php on line 15

Comment: use [autoload](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php), test2 shoud not have namespace like that

Comment: Yes, you should be autoloading these, not requiring them. Check your include paths define an `__autoload` method. If you do require these files, use `require_once`. You have a `require` in here that could cause problems.

Answer (score 2):

looks like you are using [this](https://github.com/asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client) library

if you used composer to install the library you need to include the `vendor/autoload.php` file in your code

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

it is recomneded that you use composer to install this library but if you don't want to use composer, you need to create autoloader and `require` it in your code